# How to do a filtered aggregate with Django's ORM

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model like:

```
class Post(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Topic(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Annotator(models.Model):

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='annotations')

    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

How do I find all Post records that don't have an associated Annotator record with a specific `topic` and Annotator `name` value?

Without the `topic` and `name` filtering criteria, the Django query would look like:

```
qs = Post.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(annotations_count=Count('annotations'))
qs = qs.filter(annotations_count=0)
```

but what I want to do would be something like:

```
qs = Post.objects.all()
qs = qs.annotate(annotations_count=Count('annotations' where name='annotator1' and topic='topic1'))
qs = qs.filter(annotations_count=0)
```

which obviously isn't legal.

I'm currently using `.raw()` to perform a traditional `LEFT OUTER JOIN` so I can do this filtering in the `WHERE` clause, but this prevents me from re-using a lot of code and filters I've rewritten using the Django ORM.

How do you add filtering criteria to Django's `.annotate()` method, or otherwise achieve the same result?

I'm using Django 1.11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I find all Post records that don't have an associated Annotator record with a specific topic and Annotator name value?

If I understand your question, you are looking for [`.exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
Post.objects.exclude(
    annotator__topic='topic1', 
    annotator__name='annotator1'
)
```